# my app isn't able to access the network but I have added the permission to the manifest

Tags: android

I am trying to write a web sockets client but it doesn't seem to connect to the server. But I dont get any errors. Just doesn't do anything. Therefore I tried adding a web view to see if it has access to the net. That doesn't work either.

However the browser on the emulator itself can access the internet. It also didn't ask me if I give  permission for the app to access the internet.

[image]

[image]

Here is the my manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
    
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AccentaG4"
            tools:targetApi="31" >
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
                android:exported="false"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```